# Properties of differentiable functions on non-locally-bounded fields

Tags: reference-request, topological-rings

I was reading some results on the structure of non-locally-bounded topological fields, and I was wondering what is known about differentiable functions on them.  In particular, on the complex numbers with the usual topology, differentiable functions are infinitely differentiable.  Is the same thing (or something similar) true of functions on fields with weird topologies?